# time.sleep hangs multithread function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am having trouble with a sleep statement hanging my multithreading function.  I want my function to go about it's buisness while the rest of the program runs.  Here is a toy that recreates my problem:

```
import multiprocessing, sys, time

def f(icount, _sleepTime = 1):
    for i in range(icount):
        time.sleep(_sleepTime)
        print(_sleepTime)

def main(args):
    m = multiprocessing.Process(target = f, args=(4, ))
    m.run()
    # f should be sleeping for 1 second so this print statement should come first
    print(m.is_alive())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

can anyone explain why this code outputs:

```
1
1
1
1
False
```

instead of:

```
True
1
1
1
1
```

### #

EDIT

### #

I eventually want to run this function on a schedual, and test if it is running before I execute the function.  This is an example:

```
import multiprocessing, sys, time

def f(icount, _sleepTime = 1):
    for i in range(icount):
        time.sleep(_sleepTime)
        print(_sleepTime)

def main(args):
    m = multiprocessing.Process(target = f, args=(4, ))
    for i in range(15):
        time.sleep(.5)
        if not m.is_alive():
            # m.start throws an error after first run
            m.run()
        print("{}".format(m.is_alive()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `start` and `join` instead of `run`:

```
import multiprocessing, sys, time

def f(icount, _sleepTime = 1):
    for i in range(icount):
        time.sleep(_sleepTime)
        print(_sleepTime)

def main(args):
    m = multiprocessing.Process(target = f, args=(4, ))
    m.start()
    # f should be sleeping for 1 second so this print statement should come first
    print(m.is_alive())
    m.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

#

EDIT

#

Again, use `start` and `join` instead of `run`:

```
import multiprocessing, sys, time

def f(icount, _sleepTime = 1):
    for i in range(icount):
        time.sleep(_sleepTime)
        print(_sleepTime)

def create_process():
    return multiprocessing.Process(target = f, args=(4, ))

def main(args):
    m = create_process()
    m.start()
    for i in range(15):
        time.sleep(.5)
        if not m.is_alive():
            # m.start throws an error after first run
            print("restarting")
            m.join()
            m = create_process()
            m.start()
        print("{}".format(m.is_alive()))
    m.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: Ok, my toy was a little too basic.  what i want is to definde `m = multiprocessing` outside a while loop and test if it is running before I run it again.

Comment: @posop: either create a new Process or use Pool